# Creating a Flag file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm relatively new to python so please forgive early level understanding!

I am working to create a kind of flag file. Its job is to monitor a Python executable, the flag file is constantly running and prints "Start" when the executable started, "Running" while it runs and "Stop" when its stopped or crashed, if a crash occurs i want it to be able to restart the script. so far i have this down for the Restart:

```
from subprocess import run
from time import sleep

# Path and name to the script you are trying to start
file_path = "py" 

restart_timer = 2
def start_script():
    try:
        # Make sure 'python' command is available
        run("python "+file_path, check=True) 
    except:
        # Script crashed, lets restart it!
        handle_crash()

def handle_crash():
    sleep(restart_timer)  # Restarts the script after 2 seconds
    start_script()

start_script()
```

how can i implement this along with a flag file?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with "flag", but this minimally achieves what you want.

Main file `main.py`:

```
import subprocess
import sys
from time import sleep

restart_timer = 2
file_path = 'sub.py' # file name of the other process

def start():
    try:
        # sys.executable -> same python executable
        subprocess.run([sys.executable, file_path], check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        sleep(restart_timer)
        return True
    else:
        return False

def main():
    print("starting...")
    monitor = True
    while monitor:
        monitor = start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then the process that gets spawned, called `sub.py`:

```
from time import sleep

sleep(1)
print("doing stuff...")

# comment out to see change
raise ValueError("sub.py is throwing error...")
```

Put those files into the same directory and run it with `python main.py`

You can comment out the throwing of the random error to see the main script terminate normally.

On a larger note, this example is not saying it is a good way to achieve the quality you need...

Comment: @Shone118 does this help? Or what do you mean with flag?

Comment: thanks for the help, i have a question though so the code you wrote, monitors the sub file until an exception is raised but are they supposed to be running at the same time?

Comment: No, `python main.py` calls `sub.py` in its subprocess (Line11) so it's just one call

Comment: so i changed the name not using "main" as you have and noticed that, the program does not run like its supposed to, do you have any insight on what the reason could be?

Comment: can you be more specific? what command have you tried? and what's the name of the file(s)?

Comment: i'm running the code from a python shell and i have 2 scripts open and saved in the same directory, the 2 being the parent file "main.py" and the one that gets spawned "sub.py", and i attempt to run it on the shell, only difference is i changed the file name from main to moni.py

Comment: and you call it with `python moni.py` ? What happens then?

Comment: python does not interpret it well causing no result in the shell, normally it prints searching, but when i switch the name nothing returns

Comment: could i be the fact that i changed everywhere "main" was to "moni"?

Comment: only change the file name to `moni.py` and how you call it, with `python moni.py`. Everything _in_ the code should still be `main`.

Comment: when i try it. it returns "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: my post contains valid syntax so make sure you check yours against it...